# In spring mvc display with default values in dropdown in th jsp

Tags: spring, jsp, model-view-controller

I have table of content populated on JSP, each row there is one `<button>` when we click that button form values goes to controller then I set all values to jsp using `model.addAttribute()`
 In that jsp some of the fields are dropdowns now I want to display the form value as default value to next Jsp can any one help me how can i proceed further?

sample code i wrote

in jsp

```
<form:select path="country">
  <form:options items="${countryList}" itemLabel="country"/>
  </form:select>
```

In controller method

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String getClist(@ModelAttribute("form") FormBean fb){
  sysout(fb.getCountry());

  List<Country> c =userdao.getCountryList();

  model.addAttribute("countryList",c);
}
```

Comment: I didn't get you, what I understand somehow is you wanted to show a default option to `select` like "Please select option". Please clarify if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the value that is already on the path, as well as the list for further change or selection.

```
<form:select path="country">
  <form:option value="${country}" label="${country}" />
  <form:options items="${countryList}" itemLabel="country"/>
  </form:select>
```